# Error 500 when trying to restore revision

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

So, first of all, I'm using : 
 - Laravel 5.5
 - Backpack/base 0.9.0
 - Backpack/CRUD 3.4.30
 - venturecraft/revisionable 1

And i have a little admin setting up and all. I'm mostly using CRUD features and everything works fine except for the revision. Even though I can access the list of the different revisions that happen on an element, i can't restore any of them. I've processed through backpack official doc in order to install this feature but have failed to make it to work on any of my model. Any time i try to, i got a this :

`http://myxperience/admin/offer/1/revisions/0/restore 500 (Internal Server Error)`

The issue seems to be that backpack can't get the correct revisions id, any ideas ?

Comment: (1) Does that happen on all entries, or just this one? I see this one has an id of zero - I don't think that's normal. Are you using regular IDs or something special like UUIDs on your model? (2) Please try to see what the 500 error says in more detail (what line it fails at) using Chrome Developer Tools, Network Tab, then click on the failed request (in red).

Comment: (1) This happen on all entries no matter what, not only this nested item
(1,5) I'm using regular ID

Comment: (2) The error doesn't say that much except that it's ajax related as we could guess : https://imgur.com/a/3IBEAYI

Comment: yup - please click the URL there, it should give the exact error then

Comment: The provided uri is not valid. There is not top level domain in the url (eg .com, .net, etc).

Comment: @mopsyd we are working on a .io top level domain, is there any issue related to this?

Comment: Then from the looks of the provided uri, it should be `http://myxperience.io/admin/offer/1/revisions/0/restore`. The `.io` appears to be missing from your uri.

Comment: Yeah, but in this example we aren't working on a local environnement (didn't merged it onto the pre-prod server for the moment since it's not working) so, that's why you aren't seing any top level domain in this uri.

BTW : just tried it on the pre-prod server (the one with .io) and I've got another error coming from some mixed content between http and https (server is in https and i've forced url to https in the provider)...

Comment: Add urls as `//` instead of `http://` or `https://`, which tells the browser to use the same protocol as the original request. That will work equally well on https as well as unsecured (like local dev) environments without issue.

Comment: You generally also don't want to refuse http on the server outright, but instead use a 301 redirect from unsecured to secured. That way when things like Google Webmaster Tools try to authorize ownership of both the secured and unsecured domain, they don't get bounced with a 401 when hitting the unsecured url.

Comment: Sorry about that but i didn't get what you mean in your first point, "Add urls as // instead of http:// or https://" ?